# How can I infer contacts who have ordered a product through their account?

Tags: order

I have Accounts who order a number of products. Each Account has a number of Contacts. By default, all Contacts belonging to an Account can have access to the products that the Account has ordered.

I need to write a report where the user filters by product and all the Contacts across all Accounts that have ordered this product are presented.

Anyone managed to do this without coding?! I am limited to the Professional Edition.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any limitations on reports that are unique to PE compared to EE or UE. Its simply going to be a matter of setting up the custom report to achieve the desired results. This may require a joined report of some kind to achieve what you want to accomplish. I recommend you lay out the objects you want to include along with their relationships to figure out how you're going to obtain the report results.

Some resources you may find helpful are [Getting Started with Salesforce1 Reporting](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_analytics_overview_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_analytics_overview_cheatsheet/), [Salesforce1 Reporting Workbook](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.workbook_analytics.meta/workbook_analytics/) and [Report Formula Summary Functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_report_summary_functions_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_report_summary_functions_cheatsheet/).